# JQM back transition after Google Maps API or Google Analytics completes loading

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-analytics, rhomobile

I have a strange issue with jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 and my Rhomobile 4.1.1 mobile app. I load the Google Maps API and Google Analytics at startup. However, if they have not completed loading by the time the user goes to another page, then JQM triggers a changePage back to the main page once the scripts have loaded.

On fast internet connections this does not happen. However, on slow smartphone connections, this happens frequently. I can repeat the behavior easily using the Mac OS X Network Link Conditioner tool using the "Edge Lossy Network".

I load Google Analytics this way:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456-7']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

  </script>
```

I load Google Maps API this way:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", ".startup", function(event) {
  var script_name = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=MyAPIKey&callback=Set_Google_Maps_API_Status";
  $.getScript(script_name);
});
```

I think the issue is when the script gets inserted into the DOM. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the Google Analytics code into a setTimer call to delay its execution by 5 seconds. It appears to have solved the issue.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-123456-7']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    setTimeout(function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    },5000);

  </script>
```